# Why null text set in adapter?

Tags: android, adapter

I'm confused on this problem!

I set text to `TextView` in adapter, but when my listview is generated, TextView is null yet.

My problem is about `MyAdapter` because when i put text manually it works perfectly.

Please help me.

This is my "**Adapter**" :

```
package ir.sarashpazp.peymanehsarashpaz;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

public class MainAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Activity activity;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private List<items> feedItems;
private items item;


public MainAdapter(Activity activity, List<items> feedItems) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.feedItems = feedItems;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return feedItems.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int location) {
    return feedItems.get(location);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    item = new items();
    if (inflater == null)
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null)
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.eachdastoor, null);


    TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);

    name.setText(item.getName());

    return convertView;
}

}
```

This is my "**items**" class :

```
public class items {
private int id;
private String name, status, image, profilePic, timeStamp, url;

public items() {
}

public items(int id, String name, String image, String status,
                String profilePic, String timeStamp, String url) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.image = image;
    this.status = status;
    this.profilePic = profilePic;
    this.timeStamp = timeStamp;
    this.url = url;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}


}
```

Comment: Try removing `item = new items();` line. It creates an empty object for each object in your adapter. Change it to `item = feedItems.get(position);`

Comment: thanks for your answer, what is feedPositions ??

Comment: what do you think this `item = new items();` does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are always accessing a new object instance instead of an item of you array. Please replace

```
 item = new items();
```

with

```
 item = feedItems.get(position);
```

Comment: @GamesroomIran I've made an edit to the answer. It should be `feedItems`, the array in which you store all items object in you adapter

Comment: aha, it works but all of the text in each item is "Item 5" now !

Comment: oh this is my mistake, thanks you for perfect answer

Comment: Glad it helpe :).